# How can I manually start a Camel Route through Spring XML?

Tags: java, spring, apache-camel

I've got my route's autoStart set to false:

```
<route id="myRoute" autoStartup="false">
```

Everything I can find online about how to start it after that is for starting it in java and says to call `startRoute("myRoute");` on the camelContext.. but I can't find anything about how to call that from within a route in Spring XML.

Here's my setup:

```
<route id="myRoute" autoStartup="false">
    <from uri="ftp://remote/dir" />
    <to uri="file:///local/dir" />
</route>
<route id="kickOff">
    <from uri="timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1&amp;delay=30000" />
    <!-- START myRoute HERE -->
    <to uri="bean:postProcessor?method=postProcess" />
</route>
```

My goal is to have the FTP get all the files on the FTP once, then stop that route. Currently it'll continue polling the FTP indefinitely. I tried adding a `org.apache.camel.impl.LimitedPollingConsumerPollStrategy` with a limit of 1 but that didn't seem to change anything.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

See the controlbus eip / component where you can start routes:

- http://camel.apache.org/controlbus.html

The code should be something alike:

```
<route id="kickOff">
    <from uri="timer://runOnce?repeatCount=1&amp;delay=30000" />
    <to uri="controlbus:route?routeId=myRoute&action=start" />
    <to uri="bean:postProcessor?method=postProcess" />
</route>
```

Comment: Awesome. Had a query, I need to start multiple routes with name starting with "sarada*". My routeid are sarada_main,sarada_sub1,sarada_sub2. Is this possible?